# Can't receive email on VPS server

Tags: email, unix

Since a couple of weeks I can't receive emails with a mailserver, in combination with a VPS server.

When I trace the e-mailadres on http://www.mtgsy.net/dns/utilities.php I get the following result:

---

Getting MX records for 'domein.nl'

There are 01 MX records (Mail servers) for the domain 'domein.nl'

Testing each mail server in the list using the address info@domein.nl

Testing mail.domein.nl, preference = 10

Checking to see if mail.domein.nl is in any of the popular RBL's - PASSED - Not found in any RBL's

Trying to connect to mail.domein.nl

SUCCESS

220 hosted-by.xynta.nl ESMTP Exim 4.69 Sat, 14 Aug 2010 11:54:18 +0200

EHLO MTGSY.NET

250-hosted-by.xynta.nl Hello frankfurt2.mtgsy.com [85.25.178.12]

250-SIZE 20971520

250-PIPELINING

250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN

250-STARTTLS

250 HELP

MAIL FROM: postmaster@mtgsy.net

250 OK

RCPT TO: info@domein.nl

250 Accepted

QUIT

221 hosted-by.xynta.nl closing connection

---

I think this is all OK, but when I check the Inbox with Squirrelmail I can't see the received e-mails.

I can send e-mails without problems.

Does anyone know how to find the solutions for this (big) problem? Tnx

Btw: I'm using DirectAdmin and I have root access to the server

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at /var/log/exim4/mainlog + /var/log/exim4/paniclog on the machine itself.

It looks like Exim has accepted the mail, but where it has gone afterward is a mystery.

Comment: In the mainlog everything seems ok (all completed), but in de paniclog I see: "2010-08-14 04:04:36 1Ok66u-0002ph-6k User 0 set for local_delivery transport is on the never_users list"

Is this wrong?

Comment: When I look in DirectAdmin at the emailaccounts, the size of the inbox increase when I send e-mails to the server :s

Comment: Clear you paniclog and try resending an email. If the paniclog creates new log lines post those.

Comment: Looks like squirrelmail might not be configured to load the mail from the location where it is being delivered - which explains why the size increases but you cannot see it regardless.  Check your IMAP server config.  As for "never_users list" - that means that user cannot be delivered to ..